# Replacing characters inside URL parameters via regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url, diacritics

I want to replace some diacritic characters inside URL parameter values using regular expression for finding character values.

For single character/word I make replacement with line:

```
url = url.replace(/null/g, "");
```

I can use this regular expression to find parameter values:

```
/\=[a-zA-Z0-9šŠđĐčČćĆžŽ]*\&/g
```

How to make replacement in single line (if possible)?

For example

**INPUT**: `http://localhost:8080/page?param1=svašta&param2=nešto&param3=trebam`

**OUTPUT**: `http://localhost:8080/page?param1=svata&param2=neto&param3=trebam`

Comment: Provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: By what do you want to replace them? Or just remove them like that `null`? Btw, `a-zA-Z0-9` are no diacritics…

Comment: just to remove them... I need to maintain other characters inside paramater values

Comment: Then `url = url.replace(/null|\=[a-zA-Z0-9šŠđĐčČćĆžŽ]*\&/g, "");` should do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
url = url.replace(/\=[a-zA-Z0-9šŠđĐčČćĆžŽ]*\&/g, function(match) {
    return match.replace(/[šŠđĐčČćĆžŽ]/g, "");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for that, you can use `encodeURI`

```
url = url.replace(/null/g, "");
url = encodeURI(url);
```

Comment: No, that's not what I want. I don't want percent encoded characters in my URI. IE doesn't like it ;)

Comment: Oops, I thought this was only a bug in oldIE. Then I read "*This behavior is by design.*" - like a slap in my face.

Comment: @Miki: If I read the article you link, there is a problem only with non ascii characters, I have not seen any problems with non-ascii percent encoded characters. And note that this issue appears only with old versions of IE (4.5 => 7)

Comment: You didn't read carefully enough. Read workaround again. In _Applies to_ IE versions for which it applies are 9.0, 7.0, 6.0.

Comment: @Miki: Exact, there is a problem in the automatic translation. But the problem occurs only with utf8 encoded characters, not with percent encoded characters!

Comment: _To work around this issue, do not use percent-encoded octets to represent non-US-ASCII characters ..._ Workaround from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941052